# R becomes unresponsive while running randomforest on huge data. Does this mean it is still running or it has stopped working?

Tags: r, random-forest

My data contains 229907 rows and 200 columns. I am training randomforest on it. I know it will take time. But do not know how much. While running randomforest on this data, R becomes unresponsive. "R Console (64 Bit) (Not Responding)". I just want to know what does it mean? Is R still working or it has stopped working and I should close it and start again?

Comment: Are you using a package or your own code? Have you run the code on a subset of the data to see that it works?

Comment: Sound like you are on a Mac - Use Activity Monitor to see what's going on, but 'not responding' is not usually what it says when it is simply busy.

Comment: Check memory usage. If you are out of RAM and virtual memory is used, you are out of luck. If you expect the process to run very long, I recommend not to use Rgui, but to run R from the terminal on a mac.

Comment: I am using Win 7, 4GB RAM. Not Mac. And I am using a package. I have tried using the package on small fractions(1/10) of my huge data. It works. As soon as I move to (3/10)th of data. It either becomes unresponsive or keeps working for very long. I don't know how much long to wait. R takes 5-10 min for (1/10)th of data. So, for (2/10)th of data it should take no more than 20-30 mins, I assume and so on. But it takes long more than I expect.

Comment: Get a computer with more RAM. Win7 itself already uses a large proportion of your RAM. Also, I don't think your problem scales in the way you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

It's common for RGui to be unresponsive during a long calculation.  If you wait long enough, it will usually come back.

The running time won't scale linearly with your data size.  With the default parameters, more data means both more observations to process and more nodes per tree.  Try building some small forests with `ntree=1`, different values of the `maxnodes` parameter and different amounts of data, to get a feel for how long it should take.  Have the Windows task manager or similar open at the same time so that you can monitor CPU and RAM usage.

Another thing you can try is making some small forests (small values of ntree) and then using the `combine` function to make a big forest.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your CPU usage and memory usage. If the CPU is still showing a high usage with the R process, R is probably still going strong.

Answer (score -3):

Consider switching to R 32 bit. For some reason, it seems more stable for me - even when my system is perfectly capable of 64 bit support.

Comment: I disaggree. I use R 64 bit on three different systems (Win7, Mac, Ubuntu) without any problems that would support you claim. However, a 32 bit system severely limits possible memory usage and thus makes many operations on bigger data very difficult or even impossible in R.

Comment: As terrible as it might sound, that's my go-to solution when R 64 bit goes 'Not Responding'. But I'm happy for you. Edit: Sorry, forgot to add: Running Win 7 on 4 GB ram.

Comment: Do not do this... R64 is more stable and simply better.....